# HBase BulkUpload KeyValuePair vs Put

Tags: hbase

HBase Bulkupload either can accept key-value-pairs, Puts or Deletes.

I assume Deletes is for deleting rows on mass.  How about Puts?  Is puts just  for updating a cell value where as key-value-pairs is for inserting an entire row?

---

Just to be clear the question is in the context of bulk-upload...what is the difference between bulk-uploading key-value pairs as oppose to bulkuploading puts?

---

It looks like when bulk-uploading `Put`, the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.PutSortReducer` will internally convert the puts to `KeyValue`.  Then what is the point of `Put`?  Why not just use KeyValue to begin with?

Comment: Puts are also for on mass. for ex: table.batch() or htable.put(List<Put> puts) Puts some data in the table, in batch. see https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table.html

Comment: can you eloborate " Is puts just for updating a cell value where as key-value-pairs is for inserting an entire row?"